# Выравнивание блоков текста

Tags: vim

Выделил первые элементы нескольких столбцов, не понимаю как вставить перед всеми одновременно Tab[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `>`. (9 символов нужно)

Comment: Или еще можно `=`, это автоматически выровнит код в зависимости от синтаксиса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Теперь три кнопки: `I` <Tab> <Esc>. Этого будет достаточно. «I» -- прописная.